# Как зайти в Discord через token

Tags: discord, авторизация, token

У меня вопрос: как зайти в аккаунт дискорд через токен?

Comment: я пытался найти в Google,но ничего не помогало

Comment: Актуальная инструкция по входу через токен https://discord-accounts.ru/token-info/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как я понял, речь идет о аккаунте пользователя.

Нужно внести его в локальное хранилище, после сделать перезагрузку страницы:

Для начала делаем для этого функцию, которую вставляем в консоль браузера (или клиента дискорда, нажав `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I`)

```js
function login(token) {
  setInterval(() => {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement`iframe`)
                 .contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`;
  }, 50);
  setTimeout(() => {
    location.reload();
  }, 2500);
}
```

Далее, просто пишем в консоль `login('supersecrettoken')`, где `supersecrettoken` - токен от аккаунт.

Важно: чтобы токен не был аннулирован, не выходите из дискорда кнопкой выхода в настройках, стоит заходить под аккаунтом в режиме инкогнито, далее просто закрывать окно, либо чистить локальное хранилище.

Comment: @4xun  Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: На боте это работает? (Не могу зайти через токен бота)

Comment: @4xun Есть специальные софты для этого. В обычный дискорд с бота зайти невозможно, ввиду того, что у них разные методы API для взаимодействия с дискордом. Также напомню, что бот он и есть бот, и лучше взаимодействовать с ним при помощи скриптов.

Comment: Какой например софт?

Comment: @4xun Попробуй поискать в гугле